# Creating a event on Jquery, why "this" is not been returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a shortcut for this with Jquery

```
$(el).on('mouseup touchend touchcance', function(){})
```

I'm making this way:

```
$.fn.tp = function(handler){
return this.each(function(){
     $(this).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel',function(){
        handler();
     });
})}
```

But when I try to get the id from "this" in my handler it returns "undefined":

```
$('#myDivOne').tp(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id')) // show "undefined"
})
```

how can I solve that?

Check out here: http://jsfiddle.net/0yrx2hpu/

Comment: The issue is that when you called `handler()` yourself, you didn't call it in a way that would pass on the value of `this`.  So, since it's just a normal function call, `this` will be set to the global object or in strict mode to `undefined`.  You also need to pass on the `event` to the `handler` function so it has access to the event object.  PeterKA's answer below solves both issues by letting jQuery call `handler` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many `function() {}`s. As it is, `this` is the `window` object. The following should do it:

```
$.fn.tp = function(handler){
    return this.each(function(){
         $(this).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel',handler);
    })
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0yrx2hpu/1/)

Alternatively, you could pass `this` to `handler` but you have to explicitly alias it on the other end:

```
$.fn.tp = function(handler){
    return this.each(function(){
         $(this).on('mouseup touchend touchcancel',function(){
            handler($,this)
         });
    })
}
// my event on DIV 1
$('#myDivOne').tp(function($,that){
    alert($(that).attr('id')+' clicked')   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0yrx2hpu/2/)

Comment: Not if he wants to pass `$` to the function, though I don't know why he wants that.

Comment: In JavaScript you can manually set the value of `this` in the function you're invoking, so he would do `handler.call(this, $)`, which will set the value of `this` in `handler` to the current `this` value, and will pass `$` as the first argument. http://jsfiddle.net/0yrx2hpu/3/ I also changed the demo to use `this.id` to get the element's ID. There's no need for jQuery there.

Comment: Hahaha that $ was a typo. I was testing a lot of things to solve and forgot it there. Thank you so much guys!